# Couchbase PHP SDK gives generic network error

Tags: php, couchbase

I am running a website with 2 servers for website code (in PHP), and 1 server as load-balancer. All 3 are also running couchbase instances, as part of one single cluster.

[image]

In PHP code, I using couchbase buckets as follows:

```
$cluster = new \CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091');
$greyloftWebbucket = $cluster->openBucket('some_bucket');
$query = \CouchbaseViewQuery::from('abcd', 'pqrs');
```

This arrangement works fine when all couchbase instances are running. When any one of them is closed and I try to access buckets, I get following error randomly:

```
[2015-07-17 13:46:08] production.ERROR: exception 'CouchbaseException' with message 'Generic network failure. Enable detailed error codes (via LCB_CNTL_DETAILED_ERRCODES, or via `detailed_errcodes` in the connection string) and/or enable logging to get more information' in [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php:282
Stack trace:
#0 [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php(282): _CouchbaseBucket->http_request(1, 1, '/_design/abcd...', NULL, 1)
#1 [CouchbaseNative]/CouchbaseBucket.class.php(341): CouchbaseBucket->_view(Object(_CouchbaseDefaultViewQuery))
#2 /var/www/greyloft-laravel/app/couchbasemodel.php(25): CouchbaseBucket->query(Object(_CouchbaseDefaultViewQuery))
#3 /var/www/greyloft-laravel/app/Http/Controllers/Listing.php(42): App\couchbasemodel::listings()
#4 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Listing->index()
```

That is, one time the page will load correctly and show bucket content, and then one time will show me above error. It doesn't matter if I access load balancer or any of the server directly.

Also, autofailover in `enabled` with replication set to `1` in couchbase cluster. In all 3 servers, I have set `LCB_LOGLEVEL=5`

What is happening? Is it problem in Couchbase PHP SDK or anything else? I would appreciate any help at all.

**Update:**

As per *mnunberg's* suggestion, I'm using new connection string

```
$cluster = new \CouchbaseCluster('http://127.0.0.1:8091?detailed_errcodes=1');
```

With this, the error message is now. It still pops over randomly (around half the times):

```
CouchbaseException in CouchbaseBucket.class.php line 74: The remote host refused the connection. Is the service up?
```

The autofailover is taking place. In Couchbase console log:

```
Failed over 'ns_1@<ip_address>': ok
Node ('ns_1@<ip_address>') was automatically failovered.
```

It seems to me that SDK is still trying to read the failed over node. Why is this happening? Any possible solution?

Comment: Set `detailed_errcodes=1` in the connection string to give you a more detailed error message

Comment: Also please verify that autofailover has indeed taken effect. The default AutoFailover timeout is 120 seconds (two minutes), so expect to see failures (if you've brought a node down) for two minutes until auto failover actually happens

Comment: @mnunberg thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the connection string and included the detailed message in question update. Also, the autofailover is working. Can you give any hint why is error message is popping up?

Comment: Can you also explain what the load balancer is for? is the load balancer for your site, or is it for Couchbase?

Comment: Client-side logs on the server in this case would also be extreeeemely helpful. See http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/c-2.4/logging.html. You can also use the (currently undocumented) `console_log_level` and `console_log_file` connection string options as well